# Polar set of convex cones Proof

Tags: convex-optimization, discrete-geometry

I have to show the following:
Let $K_{1}, K_{2} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be convex cones with $K_{1} \cap  K_{2} = \begin{Bmatrix}
0
\end{Bmatrix}$ and $intK_{i} \neq \varnothing , i=1,2$.

Show that $$\exists x \neq 0:x \in K_{1}^{*} \cap (-K_{2}^{*})$$, where $K_{i}^{*}$ is the polar set of $K_{i}$.

I tried a lot but without any results, which might be due to my lack of understanding of the polar set.
I'd really appreciate if someone could show me how this works or give me a useful hint.

Thanks in advance and have a good day

Comment: The statement $\exists x\neq 0 : x\in K_1^*\cap (-K_2^*)$ is equivalent to there exists a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which separates $K_1$ and $K_2$. Do you understand why I say that? If so, do you know the [hyperplane separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem)?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. At the moment, I don't really get how this is equivalent, but I will try out some more things. I do know the separation theorem.

Comment: Solved it, thanks alot.

Comment: Awesome! No problem.